# difference between imageview and com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView in android

Tags: imageview, fresco

Can someone please explain the real difference between ImageView and  com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView.and why fresco not use imageview.?

can we upload a image on server through fresco? if yes please share code..

Answer (score 2):

Unlike [Codo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35289754/3372061) that discusses the "deeper" difference between these classes (see *The Image Pipeline* section [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/concepts.html#_)), I'll discuss the usability difference.

---

Going over [the source code](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/view) of `SimpleDraweeView` and related classes one can see the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
public class SimpleDraweeView extends GenericDraweeView
public class GenericDraweeView extends DraweeView<GenericDraweeHierarchy>
public class DraweeView<DH extends DraweeHierarchy> extends ImageView
```

The following description appears before the class definition of `DraweeView`:

> Although `ImageView` is subclassed instead of subclassing `View` directly, this class does not support `ImageView`'s `setImageXxx`, `setScaleType` and similar methods. Extending `ImageView` is a short term solution in order to inherit some of its implementation (padding calculations, etc.).
>   This class is likely to be converted to extend `View` directly in the future, so avoid using `ImageView`'s methods and properties (T5856175).

So we know that `DraweeView` **presently** inherits from `ImageView` - which usually means that "it does everything `ImageView` does and more" (with the exceptions discussed in the comment block above). This simplistic approach can give you a general idea but ignores the most important aspect of compatibility with Fresco.

The [Fresco docs](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html#_) explain how to use drawees, and you can see right from their XML definition that they are much more customizable [than `ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#lattrs):

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    fresco:fadeDuration="300"
    fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@color/wait_color"
    fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
    fresco:failureImage="@drawable/error"
    fresco:failureImageScaleType="centerInside"
    fresco:retryImage="@drawable/retrying"
    fresco:retryImageScaleType="centerCrop"
    fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/progress_bar"
    fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"
    fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
    fresco:backgroundImage="@color/blue"
    fresco:overlayImage="@drawable/watermark"
    fresco:pressedStateOverlayImage="@color/red"
    fresco:roundAsCircle="false"
    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="1dp"
    fresco:roundTopLeft="true"
    fresco:roundTopRight="false"
    fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
    fresco:roundBottomRight="true"
    fresco:roundWithOverlayColor="@color/corner_color"
    fresco:roundingBorderWidth="2dp"
    fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/border_color"
  />
```

As for uploads - it seems like Fresco is only intended for **downloading** images. You might want to look into [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice)/[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for your uploading needs.

Answer (score 0):

The facebook provides its own ImageView, So rather than creating your own CustomView or ImageView you can use their View.

But, Remember you could have a less control on it as compared with your own Custom View.

This gives you a complete package and Functionality for a **Button**, **View** or Anything like that.

Like this here for Rounded Corners of a `ImageView`

```
       <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Android versions before Android 5 have serious problems with handling a large number of images. Android 2 has problems if they are on the Java heap and Android 4 doesn't properly release them if you don't destroy the activity.

So Fresco moves images to the native heap (Android 2) and implements its own reference counting for Android 4 in order to know when the image is no longer reference and can be recycled.

They replace `ImageView` with `SimpleDrawView` in order to have full control about the references to the images. In fact, only there low level API gives you direct access to the image at all. Otherwise their approach with reference counting would work.